# How do I obtain screen resolution information?

Tags: android

I need to obtain the screen resolution, width & height, how do I do that?

Solution:

```
    Display d = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();


    width = d.getWidth();
    height = d.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Display d=Display.getInstance();
int width = d.getDisplayWidth();
int height = d.getDisplayHeight();
```

According to http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=479230

or possibly

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/435390/Android/Mobile/screen-size-at-run-time

Comment: I am getting an error: The method getInstance() is undefined for the type Display.  Could you also show what to import?

Comment: works now, with this:
Display d= ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
 
width = d.getWidth();
height = d.getHeight();

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add that Eclipse didn't automatically find WindowManager for me.  You need to import android.view.WindowManager and android.view.Display.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

PLEASE first ask yourself *why* you need to do this.  You very probably don't.  If it is to do anything based on the screen size (layout etc) this will return you the *wrong* information, since it is telling you about the physical resolution of the screen, not taking into account anything like the status bar, window decorations, etc.  Even if you are running your app as full-screen, in some cases there may be parts of the screen that are used for system UI that you can't get rid of but will be included in the numbers returned by Display.

The correct thing to do is adjust for the size your view gets during layout, such as when its onSizeChanged() is called.